# Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `theme` is marked as required in `MuiThemeProviderOld`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to add Material ui ThemeProvider 
This is how i did this but its not working. While trying to console log createMuiTheme it gives all the data but its not hooking a-up with MuiThemProvider.

this is the error

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `theme` is marked as required in `MuiThemeProviderOld`, but its value is `undefined`.

This is my code.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { withStyles, MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import ChevronLeftIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';

import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import { green } from '@material-ui/core/colors';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  pallete: {
     primary: {
      "50": "#21412a",
      "100": "#21412a",
      "200": "#21412a",
      "300": "#21412a",
      "400": "#21412a",
      "500": "#21412a",
      "600": "#21412a",
      "700": "#21412a",
      "800": "#21412a",
      "900": "#21412a",
      "A100": "#21412a",
      "A200": "#21412a",
      "A400": "#21412a",
      "A700": "#21412a",
      "contrastDefaultColor": "light"
    }

  },
})
console.log(theme);

const drawerWidth = 240;

const styles = theme => ({

  link: {
    textDecoration: 'none'
  },
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
  appBar: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
  },
  appBarShift: {
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginLeft: 12,
    marginRight: 20,
  },
  hide: {
    display: 'none',
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth,
  },
  drawerHeader: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: '0 8px',
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    marginLeft: -drawerWidth,
  },
  contentShift: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
    marginLeft: 0,
  },
});

class Layout extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open: false,
  };

  handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  handleDrawerClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes, theme } = this.props;
    const { open } = this.state;

    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <CssBaseline />
          <AppBar
            position="fixed"
            className={classNames(classes.appBar, {
              [classes.appBarShift]: open,
            })}
          >
            <Toolbar disableGutters={!open}>
              <IconButton
                color="inherit"
                aria-label="Open drawer"
                onClick={this.handleDrawerOpen}
                className={classNames(classes.menuButton, open && classes.hide)}
              >
                <MenuIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" noWrap>
                Persistent drawer
              </Typography>
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>
          <Drawer
            className={classes.drawer}
            variant="persistent"
            anchor="left"
            open={open}
            classes={{
              paper: classes.drawerPaper,
            }}
          >
            <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
              <IconButton onClick={this.handleDrawerClose}>
                <ChevronLeftIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </div>
            <Divider />
            <List>
              <Link to="/" className = {classes.link}>
                <ListItem button>
                  <ListItemText primary='Home'/>
                </ListItem>
              </Link>
              <Divider/>
              <Link to='/categories' className={classes.link}>
                <ListItem button>
                  <ListItemText primary='Categories'/>
                </ListItem>
              </Link>
            </List>
          </Drawer>
          <main
            className={classNames(classes.content, {
              [classes.contentShift]: open,
            })}
          >
            <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />
            {this.props.children}
          </main>
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}


export default withStyles(styles)(Layout);
```

Comment: you are reading the theme from props, instead I think you need it from createMuiTheme, you could name it differently and use the same

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri i tried changing names but it still remains the same.

Comment: @adityakumar Try placing the theme inside your constructor as `this.theme` and passing it to the component as `theme={this.theme}`. Does the behavior stay the same?

Answer (score 1):

The first line of your `render` method should be changed from:

```
const { classes, theme } = this.props;
```

to:

```
const { classes} = this.props;
```

Currently the additional `theme` variable declaration inside your `render` is hiding the `theme` variable set above to the result of `createMuiTheme`.

Comment: i tried that too,  i don't know why its still not working.

Comment: Please share a CodeSandbox or similar that reproduces the problem.

Comment: [This is the link](https://codesandbox.io/s/r4kj7z0ovp) although i made some changes in it.

Comment: I removed some of the graphql stuff on Home so that I wouldn't have the noise of it trying to hit back-end aspects that aren't present for me and made a style change to be confident the theme was coming through (menuButton css class). I do not see any error related to MuiThemeProvider. It seems to be working fine. https://codesandbox.io/s/pwnvrzjorm